# How to define TypeScript interface for the passed object in props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Could I get some help please with the definition of an interface for the `IconArr.primary` property.

I am trying to pass it into `PrimarySkills` components --> where I have to define interface but without any luck so far.

I do not want to pass the whole object with both primary and secondary icons, so I can have two separate components but with different input data later.

```
const iconsArr = {
    primary: [
        {
            id: '0',
            imgPath: 'images/techIcons/reactjs.svg',
            name: 'React',
        },
        {
            id: '1',
            imgPath: 'images/techIcons/nextjs.svg',
            name: 'NextJS',
        },
    ],
    secondary: [
        {
            id: '0',
            imgPath: 'images/techIcons/csharp.svg',
            name: 'C#',
        },
        {
            id: '1',
            imgPath: 'images/techIcons/java.svg',
            name: 'Java',
        },
    ],
};

const Skills = (props: Props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <StyledCaption contentString='SKILLS'>PRIMARY</StyledCaption>
            <PrimarySkills iconsArr={iconsArr.primary} />
        </div>
    );
};
```

in `PrimarySkills` Component

```
interface Props {
    iconsArr: {
        primary: {
            id: string;
            imgPath: string;
            name: string;
        }[];
    };
}

const PrimarySkills = (props: Props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.iconsArr.primary.map((icon) => (
                <img src={icon.imgPath} alt={icon.name} key={icon.id} height='30' />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an interface for each item contained in the array (let's say `Icon`), then use it to properly type the `iconsArr` prop as an array of that type (`Icon[]`).

```js
interface Icon {
    id: string;
    imgPath: string;
    name: string;
}

interface Props {
    iconsArr: Icon[]
}

const PrimarySkills = (props: Props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.iconsArr.map((icon) => (
                <img src={icon.imgPath} alt={icon.name} key={icon.id} height='30' />
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Note that because you're passing `iconsArr.primary` to the `iconsArr` prop, `iconsArr` will be an array (it won't have the `primary` property). You should map through it using `props.iconsArr.map(...)` instead.

Comment: Great that's what I could not figure out, that primary property is non-existent in the child component, thank you